# Lazy Evaluation in SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, lazy-evaluation

In this piece of code from the [Spark Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#parquet-files),

```
# The result of loading a parquet file is also a DataFrame.
parquetFile = sqlContext.read.parquet("people.parquet")

# Parquet files can also be registered as tables and then used in SQL statements.
parquetFile.registerTempTable("parquetFile");
teenagers = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name FROM parquetFile WHERE age >= 13 AND age <= 19")
teenagers.collect()
```

What exactly happens in the Java heap (how is the Spark memory managed) when each line is executed?

I have these questions specifically

1. Is sqlContext.read.parquet lazy? Does it cause the whole parquet file to be loaded in memory?
2. When the collect action is executed, for the SQL query to be applied,

   a. is the entire parquet first stored as an RDD and then processed or

   b. is the parquet file processed first to select only the `name` column, then stored as an RDD and then filtered based on the `age` condition by Spark?

Answer (score -1):

> Is sqlContext.read.parquet lazy?

yes,By default all transformations in spark are lazy.

> When the collect action is executed, for the SQL query to be applied
>
> a. is the entire parquet first stored as an RDD and then processed or
>
> b. is the parquet file processed first to select only the name column, then stored as an RDD and then filtered based on the age condition by Spark?

On each action spark will generate new RDD.
Also Parquet is a columnar format, Parquet readers used push-down filters to further reduce disk IO.
 Push-down filters allow early data selection decisions to be made before data is even read into Spark.
So only part of the file will be loaded into memory.

Comment: `DataFrameReader` operations are in general not lazy. They require either metadata or data access depending on a source.

Comment: please provide the reference for your comment

Comment: The reference is in the code source of DataFrame @atulgupta

Comment: @eliasah is right here. It is best to check the code of the particular input source you use. If you prefer empirical approach just check default behavior of `SQLContext.read.json` with `RDD[String]`. Details depend on context and arguments but in worse case scenario `DataFrameReader.load` may require full data scan. This is not the case with Parquet though.