# When a column is never used in an action in spark sql, is it ever loaded into memory?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I have many columns in a Spark DataFrame, but just some of them are used, is Spark smart enough to never load into memory the unused columns?

Comment: This might help you to understand what happens, when you execute a query: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/explain.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747122/lazy-evaluation-in-sparksql. Do you mean this possibly?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases spark's optimizer should be smart enough to only load needed columns (*projection pushdown*). This is especially powerful for columnar file formats such as parquet, it means that not the entire file(s) needs to be read.

But I think in some cases its still better to make an explicit `select` statement, I think I have seen cases where the projection pushdown did not work well enough, mostly in very complex queries.

To be sure, use spark's `df.explain`

Comment: So, I think what is meant is: if you write out 3 cols from a DF with 10 cols gotten, then will it only read 3 cols initially from a data source, for example. I presume you mean this. If so, if you have a second action against a cached common DF, this would imply Catalyst is smart enough to take this also into account. I can not find such documentation. JSON?

Comment: In my experience it will do column pruning based on the columns used in transformations (selects, filter, join, groupBy, window, etc). But it is not the case with df.persist when you open a data source and do not project before the persist is called. As Raphael mentioned use the df.explain and see when it projects, also confirm that df.persist impacts the projects look into SparkUI on the tab with cached data sets, they contain info about columns and sizes that have been cached.

Comment: So did you verify? I doubt the data source is subject to column pruning.

Comment: @thebluephantom you should read this article : https://db-blog.web.cern.ch/blog/luca-canali/2017-06-diving-spark-and-parquet-workloads-example

Comment: Will do, thanks for the tip, but before I read you will state that if I have a "custom query" for spark.read.jdbc it will modify the actual statement sent?